Why created lense is not shown in Dashboard page?
Reading manuals https://nova.laravel.com/docs/lenses/defining-lenses.html
in Laravel 10 / nova 4.27 app I create a new lens with command
php artisan nova:lens Orders/MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders

and I fill methods of the created class app/Nova/Lenses/Orders/MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders.php
(with loging code):
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Lenses\Orders;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Number;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Lenses\Lens;

class MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders extends Lens
{
    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [];

    /**
     * Get the query builder / paginator for the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
    {
       \Log::info(' -1 query ::');

        return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
            $query->select(self::columns())
                ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
                ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name')
                ->withCasts([
                    'orders_count' => 'float',
                ])
        ), fn ($query) => $query->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the columns that should be selected.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function columns()
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 columns ::');
        return [
            'users.id',
            'users.name',
            DB::raw('count(orders.id) as orders_count'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available to the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 fields ::');
        return [
            ID::make('ID', 'id'),
            Text::make('Name', 'name'),

            Number::make('orders_count', 'orders_count', function ($value) {
                return $value;
            }),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available on the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 cards ::');
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 filters ::');
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available on the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 actions ::');
        return parent::actions($request);
    }

/* Title of the card
*
* @return string
*/
    public function name(): string
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 name ::');
        return 'Active users with biggest number of processing orders';
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI key for the lens.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uriKey()
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 uriKey ::');
        return 'orders-most-active-users-with-processing-orders';
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given resource is authorizable.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function authorize()
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 authorize ::');
        return true;
    }

}

As result I have no any data in Dashboard page(including text in name method).
Checking log I see only lines :
[2024-11-17 08:09:22] local.INFO:  -1 authorize ::
[2024-11-17 08:09:22] local.INFO:  -1 name ::
[2024-11-17 08:09:22] local.INFO:  -1 uriKey ::

So methods query, fields, columns are not even called. Why So ?
Additive info :
I added my MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders lens component into
app/Nova/Dashboards/Main.php file as :
    public function cards()
    {
        return [
//            new OrdersInInvoiceWithExpireDate,
//
//            new OrdersByStatusPieChart, new OrdersCompleted, new OrdersCompletedByManagerByDays,
//            new NewReleases,
//

            new MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders,

//            new Help,
        ];
    }

With this code my Dashboard is empty. If I uncomment the rest components I see them on Dashboard page.
MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders is the only  Lens component and such problems only with it.

Just a suggestion: I think you can rewrite your query() method like  return $request->withFilters(         $query->select(self::columns())             ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')             ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name')             ->withCasts(['orders_count' => 'float'])             ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')     );

@Yousha Aleayoub , I tried to remake in your way : anyway query() method is not called and no any data in dashboard

@mstdmstd did you add that lens to the main nova resource file? As in are you able to select viewing the resource through that lens from the web page

I try to put MostActiveUsersWithProcessingOrders lens under Dasboard page. Can I do it anyway ? Do you mean that I can use it only in resource page ( url nova/resources/orders ). Please, clarify that.

Please read Additive info

Looks like tp add custom data on dashboard page I need to create a new card with command like :
php artisan nova:card vendor/package

But not lense, as I tried
